# KeyError X : K-Means Clustering

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to do K-means clustering on a dataset and I am getting the `KeyError: 'x'`,

The code is as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_table('F:\\Python\\Crime Map\\2016\\data-map-1-master-all-features-coded.txt')
df.head()
```

Output is,

```
Label   Sector  Lat Long    Seasonal    Seasonal_coding Temporal    Temporal_coding
0   1   SEC 29 GGN  28.463061   77.073010   December    12  Night   3
1   2   SEC 29 GGN  28.463061   77.073010   December    12  Night   3
2   3   sadar   28.429772   77.037971   January 1   Night   3
3   4   sadar   28.429772   77.037971   January 1   Night   3
4   5   DLF PH.2    28.487618   77.091191   January 1   Night   3
```

Then I run the following,

```
x = df['Lat']
y = df['Long']

np.random.seed(200)
k = 3
# centroids[i] = [x, y]
centroids = {
    i+1: [np.random.randint(0, 80), np.random.randint(0, 80)]
    for i in range(k)
}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='m')
colmap = {1: 'r', 2: 'g', 3: 'b'}
for i in centroids.keys():
    plt.scatter(*centroids[i], color=colmap[i])
plt.xlim(0, 80)
plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.show()
```

And get the following error,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'x'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-030419c861c4> in <module>
      8 
      9 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
---> 10 plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color='m')
     11 colmap = {1: 'r', 2: 'g', 3: 'b'}
     12 for i in centroids.keys():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'x'

<Figure size 360x360 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: According to `df.head()`, your data frame doesn't have columns called `x` and `y`, but you're trying to access them here: `plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], ...)`. They don't exist, so you get the error. Did you mean `plt.scatter(x, y)`?

Comment: @ForceBru Please note that I am defining `x` and `y` as ```x = df['Lat']
y = df['Long']```

Comment: Indeed. However, `x` is very different from `df['x']`